# Change DateInput widget's format to SHORT_DATE_FORMAT

Tags: django, localization, django-forms

I'm trying to set the `format` of a `DateInput` to `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT`. However, the following code does not work work.

forms.py

```
from django.conf.global_settings import SHORT_DATE_FORMAT

class EventForm(ModelForm):
    # ...
    startDate = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            format=SHORT_DATE_FORMAT
        )
    )
```

In the views.py, an example entry is read from the database and a form is created using `form = EventForm(instance=event1)`. The template then shows that widget using `{{form.startDate}}`. The input shows up correctly, only it's value is not a date but just "m/d/Y".

It would work if I'd set `format='%m/%d/%Y'`, however, that defeats the purpose of the locale-aware `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT`. How can I properly solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to overwrite the `DateInput` widget as follows.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import date

class ShortFormatDateInput(DateInput):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super(DateInput, self).__init__(attrs)

    def _format_value(self, value):
        return date(value, formats.get_format("SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"))
```

It overwrites the super constructor so that the date format cannot be changed manually anymore. Instead I'd like to show the date as defined in `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT`. To do that, the `_format_value` method can be overwritten to reuse the `date` method defined `django.templates`.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ! Some minor improvements: You can remove the definition of `__init__` since it's not doing anything ; I find it more readable to rename the `date` import to something like `date_template_filter`